# Python - count occurrences in list of list

Tags: python

I'm new to python, I'm therefore sorry if this question might be stupid. I have a list of lists that looks like this:

```
a = [['P - tag1', 'A - tag2', 'P - tag2', ' B - tag1', 'P - tag3'],['A - tag2', 'B - tag1'],['P - tag2', 'B - tag1','P - tag 3]]
```

What I want to do is count the number of lists that have at least one element that contain the string 'P -'. In this example the answer would be 2.

Then I would also like to count the lists that have n number of elements containing the 'P -' string. Let's say I want to know how many lists have 2 'P -' elements (1 in the given example). What would be the easiest and more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you put your attempt and then someone can help you in directing to the right path. From what it seems you have to basically iterate over lists using for loop and test for the conditions you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

This will do it, its a list comprehension that will check if sublist has at least `n` elements that contain `P -`:

```
 n = 1
 len([i for i in a if len([j for j in i if 'P -' in j])>=n])
```

You just change `n` to specify bottom limit.

Comment: What if the list item contains `tag2 P - tag3`?

Comment: Example suggested begging of string is what OP is looking for.

Comment: Thats not specific. What if OP is just showing a sample?

Answer (score 1):

I have already seen some nice answers here, however, here is also an explanation of why these work.

#### Explanation

Lets break this question down, first lets take a look at how we can see if a string contains `P -`:

```
string_a = 'P - tag1'
string_b = 'A - tag2'

'P -' in string_a # yields True
'P -' in string_b # yields False
```

Now we check whether any item in a list contains an item for which `P -` in `item` is True. We loop over a list with list comprehension:

```
lst = ['P - tag1', 'A - tag2', 'P - tag2', ' B - tag1', 'P - tag3']
any(['P -' in item for item in lst]) # Yields True because there are items containing 'P -'
```

Next we apply this to all our nested lists and count the number of items in your list using `sum()`

```
sum(any(['P -' in item for item in lst]) for lst in a)
```

Comment: Thanks, really useful explanation! The code you provided works perfectly, but I wanted to double-check the result by counting the number of occurrences that does NOT contain 'P -' but this doesn't work: `sum(any(['P -' not in item for item in lst]) for lst in a)`. What mistake am I making?

Comment: In the case where you do NOT want any to result to contain 'P -', you should check that `all` values in lst do not contain 'P -'. The statement will then become `sum(all(['P -' not in item for item in lst]) for lst in a)`

Answer (score 0):

I have made a code that works as expected. It loops the the list and then loops through the item in the sub-list. If `p -` is found in the item then it adds 1 in total and break that loop immediately (because one `P -` tag is required in list) and continue to the next sub-list.

```
a = [['P - tag1', 'A - tag2', 'P - tag2', ' B - tag1', 'P - tag3'],['A - tag2', 'B - tag1'],['P - tag2', 'B - tag1','P - tag 3']]
contains = 0
for aa in a:
    for aaa in aa:
        if "P -" in aaa:
            contains += 1
            break
print(contains)
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a helper function to count elements having `P` in a list

```
def countP(lst):
    return sum(1 for item in lst if 'P-' in item)
```

and then, assuming `my_list` is your initial list, and `n` your threshold

```
result= sum(1 for sublist in my_list if countP(sublist) > n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just look for pattern `'P -tag'` in the inner list converted to string without iterating over the entire inner list.

```
sum([1 for i in a if 'P - tag' in ''.join(i)])
```

Comment: what if one element is 'AAP' the next one is ' - whatever' your code would count wrongly

Comment: Then look for the whole pattern `P - tag` number is not consistent. I am trying to avoid nested loops like other answers have

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to group the lists in your list by occurrence of `'P -'`:

```
>>> a = [['P - tag1', 'A - tag2', 'P - tag2', ' B - tag1', 'P - tag3'],['A - tag2', 'B - tag1'],['P - tag2', 'B - tag1','P - tag 3']]
>>> res = [(f'list{i}', sum(1 for j in l if 'P -' in j)) for i,l in enumerate(a, start=1)]
>>> res
[('list1', 3), ('list2', 0), ('list3', 2)]
>>> sum(1 for i in res if i[1] > 0)
2
```

`res` contains the count of the occurrences per list, and the sum of 2 is the result of counting all lists that contain at least 1 occurrence. Counting all occurrences in all lists would be `sum(i[1] for i in res)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(x > 0 for x in [sum([1 for s in i if s.startswith("P -")]) for i in a])
```

change x > 0 to x > i to count other occurrence rates.

How does this work?

`[1 for s in i if s.startswith("P -")]` returns 1 for every string that begins with P -

Sum function and [] surrounding it will then return a list with count of those strings

finally outer sum will get you your desired output.

This should answer both of your questions!